# Bitcoin Core not loading transactions

Tags: bitcoin-core, sparrow-wallet

I now have a full node on an external drive, no pruning.
I connected sparrow to Bitcoin Core, but now the wallet in Sparrow and the same wallet on Bitcoin Core is missing 4 transactions, and then of course shows an incorrect balance, and a list of my utxos before those 4 transactions.

If I disconnect from Bitcoin Core and connect back to a public server it will then show all transactions again like normal.

The 4 transactions have over ten thousand confirmations and my node is fully synced to the latest block.

What can be the explanation for this?

Comment: Is it possible to import a key into Sparrow, without importing it into Bitcoin Core?

Comment: Hi RedGrittyBrick, I may have misunderstood your question, and maybe it wasn’t for me, but here it goes: whenever I load a wallet in Sparrow it automatically appears in Bitcoin Core. I am not sure if one can disable this.

Comment: Is your Bitcoin Core node fully synced?

Comment: Hi Pieter Wuille, yes it is.

Comment: Have you configured pruning in bitcoin.conf

Comment: Did you create the affected wallet with sparrow connected to a public server and not connected to Bitcoin core?

Comment: Does this apply: [I’ve restored my wallet but some of my funds are missing](https://sparrowwallet.com/docs/faq.html#ive-restored-my-wallet-but-some-of-my-funds-are-missing)

Comment: All I have in conf file is "server=1". And yes, I created the wallet long before I started running a Bitcoin Core node. I should have added that the 4 transactions that are missing are the most recent ones. I tried drastically increasing gap limit in Sparrow but the results were the same.

Comment: update: there must have been some sort of file corruption or something, because now I cannot even start bitcoin core, it never syncs headers… Thank you regardless, RedGrittyBrick.